# How to handle more concurrent users on a Flask App that connects to Heroku PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, flask, heroku, heroku-postgres

My Flask API on Heroku has many endpoints that runs queries on my Heroku PostgreSQL database before returning the jsonified results to the client.

My current plan is a Hobby Basic tier, so the database can handle only 20 connections maximum.

If I set the `--workers` in gunicorn to something like 17, it works fine and I can handle about 1000 users sending two HTTP requests each at the same time.

But if I want to scale my API up to be able to handle a large userbase, how do I do so? 1000 concurrent user requests have a good response time with an average of 2.5s, but if I bump it to 2000 or above, it goes above 7s and such.

- Using the current Basic tier, how can I efficiently make use of what I have? I have heard of Connection Pooling, will this help?
- If the only way to scale up would be to pay more, how should I do it? Would it be as simple as upgrading the Database tier to Standard, and upping the workers to 100+?

Comment: What database library are you using to connect to postgres?

Comment: @TedElliott psycopg2

Comment: Isn't  gunicorn  already doing connection pooling?